# Find the Lipschitz constant of $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Find the Lipschitz constant of

$$g(x)=\sqrt{x}$$

for

$$1\leqslant x\leqslant2$$

Any idea of how to start?

Answer (score 2):

By the mean value inequality we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\sup_I|f'(x)||x-y|$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: ok L= sup(1/2sqrt(x)), take x=1, then L=1/2

Comment: Yes that's right!